# Disable annoying acceleration for sound volume keys

Tags: windows-10, audio, keyboard

I have sound volume keys on my keyboard to increase and decrease volume. This panel appears when i change volume:

[image]

Each key changes volume by 2% per single press. When i quickly press increase key 10 times i get sound volume increased by 20%. But as for decreasing key - i getting volume decreased by 50%! It starts slowly, by 2% per 1 press, but eventually percentage grows over 10% per single press. I wanted to decrease volume by 20% or so, but got too quiet sound or even muted. Now it becomes very annoying for me!

Does anybody know how to disable this volume decreasing acceleration?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's key repeat delay & speed settings somewhere in Windows... does searching it's help/config/control panel find them, does changing them help? Sounds almost like you're pressing the key so fast that it's interpreted as holding it down - what happens when just holding down either volume key?

Comment: I assume your tag "windows-7" was an error, and corrected it to "windows-10".

Comment: Xen2050, i agree, somewhere in windows should be some config with this delay option and presses count threshold that defines when to start the acceleration. I already tried to find such config options in control panel, in windows settings search, and in registry by relevant words.... and obviously i failed.

Comment: If i just holding down the key - windows does not apply the acceleration, the volume just quickly goes down by 2% steps, the steps speed depends on regular keyboard keys repeat option.

Comment: @IDizor, unfortunately this does not allow for the desired fine control. As a human (totally not a robot), measuring such a small period of time is very inaccurate, but it is much easier to count quickly successive key presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround solution made by myself using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

```
volDecreaseCounter := 0

~Volume_Down::
{
  global volDecreaseCounter
  volDecreaseCounter := volDecreaseCounter + 1
  
  SoundGet, currentVolume
  
  if (currentVolume > 2 && volDecreaseCounter > 4)
  {
    volDecreaseCounter := 0
    Send {Volume_Up}
    Send {Volume_Down}
  }
  
  return
}
```

Just added this ahk script to the windows Startup.

Answer (score 2):

`Win+R`, type `regedit`

Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Audio`.

Change `VolumeAccelThreshold` value to 0. Reboot.

If that didn't work, the path could also be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Audio`.

(Leaving it here, so I can find it later, since this page is the first google search result.)

Comment: Thank you!
This worked for me on Windows 10 using a rotary encoder to adjust the volume.

Comment: I like my AutoHotkey solutions to things, but this is the real answer to this question!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.  Mine isn't a complete answer, but I did find a way to change the keyboard's "repeat" setting.  Hopefully it will help.

[image]

Like IDizor, my work-around is to avoid tapping the volume keys, and instead hold them down.  When I do that the volume goes up and down by 2% steps without accelerating.  But, when I tap the volume keys the volume moves at 2%, then 10%, which is very annoying.

Comment: This is a system-wide change and is not what question is about. Also this does not solve automated scripts that try to make the sound volume change by counting how many times to send the keypress signal to the system.

Comment: Interesting workaround, but now it will not work for me. Now I have a new keyboard where volume keys are replaced with wheel. It is pretty convenient I should say. It does a lot of "taps" when I spin it. Therefore I cannot just hold a volume down key.